# Should clicking already selected UI item be handled normally or ignored?

Tags: user-interface, user-experience

Lets say you have a user-interface with a tree view, and you click on already selected item. Should the click-event be handled normally or ignored (since the item is already selected)? Lets also assume that performing normal click-handling involves lots of lengthy calculations, but in overall takes less than 200 ms.

In other words you can "optimize" away lots of lengthy calculations, and just return right away, or you can force update everything, just to make sure that everything is up to date. As a side effect of second case you can "hide away" some bugs, in cases when some information is not up to date, but user can always rely on that clicking in UI would recalculate everything.

Comment: Your decision will depend entirely on your software's usability requirements.  There are pros and cons to each.  Anecdotally, most of the applications I've seen do not update when you click on the same thing, but do update if you press the Enter key or perhaps F5.

Comment: Yeah, most of applications seem to prefer to ignore the second click. For example even this google search is not doing anything when you click "Web" tab for the second time: https://www.google.fi/search?q=seldomly&espv=2&biw=1040&bih=702&source=lnms&sa=X&ved=0CAYQ_AUoAGoVChMIk6mjmI7GyAIVgX8sCh3WrgfX&dpr=1#q=test

Comment: So infuriating... Need to file a complaint to google ;)

Comment: Sometimes, handling an action normally looks like ignored to the user.

Comment: That's even better.

Comment: Many users double-click when they should just single-click, and don't really understand the difference all that well (some double-click everything). A double-click should therefore be treated as a single-click if there is no specific action associated with double-click.

Answer (score 1):

I'd look at around at your OS, popular applications for it, and maybe consider copying what they do if the selection functionality is proprietary with familiarity as the number one kind of thing to consider.

What I've noticed is that for situations where there is a start/end selection cursor, as with the case of text controls like I'm using to write this answer, then clicking anywhere will start dragging a new selection, and if you just click and release it'll have the effect of clearing your existing selection and making an empty one. In that case the empty selection is a particularly common use case since if I begin typing with something selected, it'd replace that text, so that case seems tailored to frequently working with empty selections, with a text selection being a very "transient" sort of idea, and any sort of clicking without dragging basically emptying/clearing the selection.

Usually for controls where there is generally at least more of a "dedicated item selection" (the empty selection isn't such a common case), and clicking would select something else, in my experience I often see a second click to something already selected being ignored.

One last selection model I've seen that I particularly like that I saw on Mac when one-button mice for it was popular was a single-button design which I thought was nice but I don't see it so widely used. That one would toggle selection on/off if you repeatedly click on an item. Basically that works like this:

```
on mouse down:
     if item under mouse cursor is selected:
          remove item from selection and begin deselection drag
     else: // if item is not selected
          add item to selection and begin selection drag
```

I found that pleasant and fast and intuitive (you can just start dragging and deselecting items without any modifier keys if the first item under your cursor when you started dragging is deselected, or start dragging and selecting items and adding to the existing selection without modifiers keys if the item initially under your mouse cursor was unselected), and it especially tends to work well with the stylus on tablets. But it's not a selection scheme I see widely used that often. But it allows you to add to your selection, subtract from it, toggle selection, etc, all with just one button.

Answer (score 1):

**What is a UI?**

A UI is just a fancy way to present a set of actions and choices to a user, be it textual, graphical, or tactile. Moving a mouse, clicking a button, glaring at a camera are actions available to the user. Playing a sound, colouring a monitor, or blinking a LED are ways a UI can inform the user of what is happening or of what is possible. So the raw mechanism itself isn't that interesting, but the underlying Model is.

**UI Models**

It should be possible to completely change the exterior skin of a UI. A tactile UI could be represented by a virtual 3-d object (imagine a keyboard), and still produce similar interaction to if it had been made physical and been interacted with, as far as the UI is concerned. Like a virtual/real hand pressing the ? button.

The operating system already does this. You can find keyboards that are purely graphical, are operated by voice, or that are corporeally attached via usb. The program is presented with and allowed to interact with a model of it (maybe several depending on instances).

Unfortunately these models are usually too generic, too complicated, or too simple for the applications we write. The solution is to feed this through an intermediate model, a UI model. This model sits between the platforms interface models, and the applications domain models, and has the thankless task of translating state and actions between the two.

**Semantic Action**

What happens when the user clicks the mouse button, when the mouse is in a certain position on the screen, comes down to semantics. That is the rule that decides if that event has meaning.

So if a user clicks on a button, it prints a piece of paper, this is the meaning of clicking here.

- But what is the meaning of a double click?
- Should it print out two copies?
- ignore the second click?
- How long should the second click be ignored for until its assumed that the user really wants a second copy?

Welcome to *User Experience* design.

**User Experience**

So should clicking on a selected item:

1. do some lengthy processing
2. do nothing

I would imagine that the UI could quickly check the state of the system. If there is some sort of lengthy processing it should be apparent that either the action is in progress currently, or that there are some results/obvious system state from a completed processing attempt. If not then the business logic is lacking in self-awareness and cannot reliably be shutdown.

If there is any issue, the results are too old, or the desired state was not already achieved, the semantic should be to attempt the processing again.

On the other hand if the system is in the desired state, the action is in looking fine and being processed now, or there is a not before noticed blocking reason then the semantic could reasonably be do nothing.

If the user keeps attempting the action (and the UI keeps doing nothing) then the UI semantic should be to acknowledge the user. This might be the third/forth attempt and the UI should express that the system is already working on it. It should also give the user the option to cancel and retry (if sensible). If not sensible the UI should communicate that it can not fulfill the request (like the network appearing to be down).

Answer (score 1):

OnClick is different from OnSelect and should be treated separately. One can select items with a keyboard or with a script. OnClick occurs when a mouse button is clicked at a time the mouse cursor is over the item.

The response to the click is up to the application programmer. The control implementation should be agnostic and just tell what happens.

Answer (score 1):

This wholly depends on the needs of both the user and the developer.

As a practical example, SourceTree shows you the file status of your changes. If I make a few more changes, the screen should auto update and see these new changes.
But sometimes it doesn't. And in order to refresh it manually, I can't just click the already active tab. I have to click another tab, and then back on File Status. The problem is that these other tabs also perform some calculations when selection, so now I'm stuck waiting for *two* calculations, one of which is irrelevant to me.

There are many solutions to this. Firstly, you could ensure that SourceTree always sees the file changes and never misses (but that's not accounting for anything that goes wrong, even if it's the file system that messed up). Secondly, you could add a manual refresh button. However, in absence of any of those possible solutions (for whatever reason), I would really like it if clicking the already selected tab would trigger a refresh.

Back to your case. The same logic applies here. **What is the purpose of clicking an already active tab?** There could be many purposes, e.g.:

- Unselecting is a needed user command, when nothing is selected another pane is displayed
- The displayed data could have changed since the last time the tab was loaded
- ...

If there is a purpose to it, then you have your answer: do the thing that fulfills the purpose.

If there is no purpose to it, then any action taken by re-selecting it is by definition redundant, so there's no point to doing it.

However, do take into account that **focusing on this issue is a time cost**. If the behavior is inconsequential, simply ignore it (whether it triggers the calculations or not by default) unless it presents an actual problem.

If anything, that is the best thing to take away here. **Only spend time trying to fix things when they are an actual problem**, because when you have a problem outset, it's much easier to decide on what the solution needs to be.
As it stands, your question is "what should I do?", but it'd be a lot more productive if your question was "this is what should happen; how do I do it?". The current format is really just a matter of personal preference.